# Using writeUnshared & readUnshared to communicate with sockets... reading the object I sent before and not the one I am sending right now

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I have a Server, a RMI Server and a Client...

I am using writeUnshared and readUnshared to communicate with sockets, but when I am reading, I read the object I sent (from the client to the server) before and not the one I am sending right now...

I know that I am sending, from the Client, the object I want to send... But in the Server side I am reading the object I sent before...

```
     try {
        while (true) {

            postCard = null;
            postCard = (ClientRequest) reciver.readUnshared();

            alterRequest = postCard.getRequestID() + ("_" + myUserID);
            postCard.setRequestID(alterRequest);
            System.out.println(postCard.getRequestID());

            System.out.println("[Server] Li a mensagem do cliente na boa.");
            //mudar depois para um switch
            if (postCard.getRequest()[0].equals("log")) {

                postCard.setStage(1);
                myMail = remoteConection.verificaLogIn(postCard);

                if (myMail.getResponse()[0].equals("userrec")) {
                    myUserID = (int) myMail.getResponse()[1];
                }

                myMail.setStage(4);

            } else if (postCard.getRequest()[0].equals("new")) {
                System.out.println("Fui chamado!");
                if(postCard.getResponse()!=null){
                    System.out.println("Não és null por que caralho!&");
                }

                postCard.setStage(1);

                myMail = remoteConection.novoUtilizador(postCard);

                if (myMail.getResponse()[0].equals("infosave")) {
                    System.out.println("myUserID:" + (int) myMail.getResponse()[1]);
                    myUserID = (int) myMail.getResponse()[1];
                }
                else if (myMail.getResponse()[0].equals("erro")){
                    System.out.println("ERRO!\n"); //Temos que tratar o erro
                }
                else if(myMail.getResponse()[0].equals("user_already_exists")){
                    System.out.println("User: "+ (String)myMail.getResponse()[1]+" already exists!");
                }

                myMail.setStage(4);

            } else if (postCard.getRequest()[0].equals("new_project")) {

                postCard.setStage(1);

                myMail = remoteConection.novoProjecto(postCard);

                if (myMail.getResponse()[0].equals("infosave")) {
                    System.out.println("myProjectID:" + (int) myMail.getResponse()[1]);
                    myProjectID = (int) myMail.getResponse()[1];
                }

                myMail.setStage(4);

            } else if (postCard.getRequest()[0].equals("seesal")) {

                System.out.println("Esteve aqui, como era suposto\n");

                postCard.getRequest()[1] = myUserID;
                postCard.setStage(1);

                myMail = remoteConection.getUserSaldo(postCard);

                myMail.setStage(4);
            }

            sender.writeUnshared(myMail);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("[Server]");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The connection with RMI escapes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read/writeUnshared()` only avoid sharing  the actual object being written. All dependent (reachable, member) objects remain shared.

Try a `reset()` before each write.

Comment: That's the correct answer! I was forgetting to reset() before a write, thank you!